# Automatically reinstall application after identify missing files-setup project c# visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I created Setup Project in visual studio 2015.

I would like to check all necessary files exists after

```
InitializeComponent();
```

And if any of the files is missing I would like to re-install the application.

Any suggestion about the right way to process it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to do this at all. An MSI install is a transaction where either all the files are installed and the install succeeds, or it rolls back and puts the system back to its original state. By design and definition, if it gets to the end then it has succeeded and the files are installed.

If files are removed after the install, then there's a Repair option that will reinstall them, and using a shortcut can also result in a repair.

If you have custom actions that alter the system, then that's why there are rollback custom actions - if the install fails and rolls back then your rollback custom actions are called to undo whatever you did.

In any case you can't install the same MSI again. The ProductCode defines that product on the system, and reinstalling the same MSI will result in a maintenance/repair, not a reinstall.